# Grab certain strings from text file and put into csv

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a text file with hundreds of lines of data - each separated by a newline.

**data.txt:**

```
......Tue Dec 13 [alphanumeric1.alphanumeric1] : blah [alphanumeric1] ? blahblah [alphanumeric1] : blah
..Tue Dec 13 [alphanumeric2.alphanumeric2] : blah [alphanumeric2] ? blahblah [alphanumeric2] : blah
..................Tue Dec 13 [alphanumeric3.alphanumeric3] : blah [alphanumeric3] ? blahblah [alphanumeric3] : blah
```

Each line varies in length and are unique, but each has three sets of [ ]'s and the data inside is what I want.

The goal is to read in data.txt line by line, sucking out the data in [ ]'s putting each into its own column in a csv.

**result.csv:**

```
    col1                         col2            col3

    alphanumeric1.alphanumeric1  alphanumeric1   alphanumeric1
    alphanumeric1.alphanumeric2  alphanumeric2   alphanumeric2
    alphanumeric1.alphanumeric3  alphanumeric3   alphanumeric3

So thats:
alphanumeric1.alphanumeric1,alphanumeric1,alphanumeric1
alphanumeric1.alphanumeric2,alphanumeric2,alphanumeric2
alphanumeric1.alphanumeric3,alphanumeric3,alphanumeric3
```

I've got the text file opening fine:

```
$fh = fopen('data.txt','r');
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
   echo $line;
}
```

But I'm having problems with the preg_match and getting the [ ] data into a csv.

```
preg_match('/\[(.+)\]/', $line, $matches);
```

Any help with the preg_match and pushing that data into a .csv would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose to work with `preg_match_all` since it will capture more then one occurance of the pattern within `$line`. Secondly I modified the regular expression to the following

```
    preg_match_all('/\[([^\]]+)\]/', $line, $matches);
```

What `[^\]]+` says is match at least one char which isn't a `]`. You can change the modifier `+` to `*` if you also want to catch empty occurances, ie. `[]`.